How can I get the SOL balance change for a pumpfun swap?
I am trying to get the SOL balance change for a pumpfun swap transaction in Typescript. The transaction response I am getting from getTransaction() only seems to contain the pumpfun token balance changes inside the preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances objects in transaction.meta, but no information about the SOL balance change.
As an example, this transaction https://solscan.io/tx/JFEMBvd7k5iiyytvX3Cw4SATRfeVyhpKVjifTEcp2q6PAr1Q4Kr5TSjHmwrj5xfyWYBFZJYBUzMCT6AqpewsjPM#solBalanceChange shows a SOL balance change of 0.0001 on Solscan but the transactionResponse object only contains information about the token balance change.
How can I also be able to access the SOL balance change?

If you use getTransaction, along with preTokenBalances and postTokenBalances, you'll also get preBalances and postBalances, which specifically contain the SOL balances of all accounts.
More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction#result

how will i map each value in the preBalances and postBalances arrays to the correct tokens they represent?

preBalances and postBalances only represent the lamports (SOL) in accounts, and they are given in the order of the transaction.message.accountKeys field
